# Rewrite rule not working on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url

```
http://localhost/sample/eventcentre.php?url=someurl
```

to

```
http://localhost/sample/vn/someurl
```

Here is my current rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^vn/([^/\.]+)?$ /eventcentre.php?url=$1 [L]
```

it doesn't seem to be working. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Set the base as `/sample/`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase ... or remove the leading anchor.

Comment: Didn't work. Is it because its localhost? Do I have to tweak a setting in Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

In the rewrite rule you've listed here, it starts with a `^` - this denotes the start of the rewrite.

The example urls you have start with `sample` - so if you amend the two together it should work ie:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sample/vn/([^/\.]+)?$ /eventcentre.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Didn't work. Is it because its localhost? Do I have to tweak a setting in Apache server?